# Export all the still frames from a video file?

Tags: video, image-processing

I'm looking for a way to export all the still frames from a local video file programmatically, I've tried Processing and OpenFrameworks but they only seem to deal in realtime video, I've also looked at vidsynth but it is Windows only....

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ffmpeg here is the command

ffmpeg -i inputfile.avi -r 1 -f image2 image-%3d.jpeg

Comment: Having problems installing ffmpeg, many dependencies, is there a "one line" way of installing it?

Comment: On ubuntu sudo apt-get install ffmpeg , REDHAT based system yum install ffmpeg

Comment: In the end I used macports to install it, much easier http://www.macports.org/install.php